# What dimensions is the log in screen image for Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, login

I want to change the picture that shows up on the login screen that is next to the name. ?x?px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default images provided with Windows 7 for the user pictures are all 128x128 pixels (found in `%systemdrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures`). It seem that images larger than this are cropped and images smaller than this are padded.

Answer (score 0):

The login screen background can be any size you want.  It just has to be under 256K.  There a many tools out there to change it.  TweakLogon is the one I use.

Otherwise, you can just fireup the registry editor.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/jamesone/archive/2009/05/07/customizing-the-windows-7-logon-screen-no-additional-tools-required.aspx

Comment: I'm pretty sure Negative means the user picture and not the login screen background.

Comment: I initially assumed he/she meant the background image too.

Comment: Ah fail. I assumed otherwise cause changing the user picture is just doing Control Panel/User Accounts. . .